# Moving Objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I just started with learning of JS, got fairly good knowledge of html/xml along with C/C++ and would rly like to learn JS.

I'm following a book about it and I'm on a chapter with moving objects but when I write the code it doesn't move the object as it's suppose to.
Here's my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Moving elements </title>
<script type = "text/javascript">
function moveIt(movee, newTop, newLeft){
    dom = document.getElementById(movee).style;
    dom.top = newTop + "px";
    dom.left = newLeft + "px";
 }
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form action = "">
 <p>
    x coordinate: <input type = "text" id = "leftCoord" size = "3" />
    <br />
    y coordinate: <input type = "text" id = "topCoord" size = "3" />
    <br />
    <input type = "button" value = "Move it"
            on click =
                "moveIt('Nebula',
                document.getElementById('topCoord').value,
                document.getElementById('leftCoord').value)" />
    </p>
    </form>

    <div id = "Nebula" style = "position: absolute;
        top: 115px; left: 0;" />
        <img src = "nebula.jpg"
        alt = "(Picture of a nebula)" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

So the form and the input areas / button are all on the right places but the pic isn't moving when I click on the button and I just can't figure out why...I'm running it on w7 over chrome.

Comment: Do not separate this: `on click` , make it: `onclick`

Comment: Press F12 in Chrome and look at the console tab.

Comment: Why you have the point of commenting something like that? If I said sth instead of something that doesn't mean I don't know the language it means I'm lazy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not separate this: `on click` , make it: `onclick`.

Working:
http://plnkr.co/edit/A7ddt6rtA8qf1ikBZJh1?p=preview